# $A^3 = A^2$ How can $A$'s minimal polynomial look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

> Let $K$ be a field and $A \in K^{n \times n}$ a matrix with $A^3 = A^2$.
>   How can $A$'s minimal polynomial $\mu_A$ look like?

The only possibilities I could think of are

1. $A = 0$. Then the characteristic polynomial is $P_A(t) = -t^n$.
2. $A = E$, where $E$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.  Then the characteristic polynomial is $P_A(t) = (1 -t)^n$.

I am surely missing some possibilities.
How can I draw a conclusion about the minimal polynomial from characteristic polynomial, knowing that the exponents in the first are the sizes of the largest Jordan blocks.

Comment: Note that $A^3-A^2=0$. $\mu_A$ must be a divisor of $x^3-x^2$.

Comment: Any divisor of $X^3-X^2$ can be the minimal polynomial. Don't forget  rings of matrices are not integral domains.

Comment: Note that the minimal polynomial must divide the annhilitaor polynomial (any polynomial f such that $f(A)=0$ ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial. Because of Hamilton-Cayley's theorem, we have $m(x) | x^3-x^2$.

So $m(x)$ can be $x,x-1$ (as you said) , but also

- $x(x-1)$ for example in $$\begin{bmatrix}
      1       & 0 \\
      0       & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}$$
- $x^2$ for example in $$\begin{bmatrix}
      0       & 1 \\
      0       & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}$$
- $x^2(x-1)$ for example in $$\begin{bmatrix}
      1       & 0 & 0 \\
      0       & 0 & 1 \\
      0       & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}$$

In general, given a polynomial $p$ such that $p(A)=0$ any $m(x) | p(x)$ can be $A$'s minimal polynomial.

Comment: So the conditions for $p$ being the minimal polynomial are $p(A) = 0$ and $p(t) \vert t^3 - t^2$ ?

Comment: No! A polynomial of the form you said CAN be a minimal polynomial, given $A^3=A^2$. Now, of course there is only one minimal polynomial, which depends on $A$!

Comment: But we're not given A in the exercise.

Comment: Indeed, the polynomial can assume that values, but we do not know which one it is, it depends on $A$.